# Bootstrap 3: wizard with form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a wizard with a form validation with bootstrap. I use the Twitter Bootstrap Wizard Plugin from http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/. It uses jQuery Validate Plugin.

My problem is now that the **validation of radio buttons does not work**. I can skip through the "tabs" even if no radio button is checked.

Has anyone an idea what I've made wrong?

This is my Javascript-Code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $validator = $("#commentForm").validate();

    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
        'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
        'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
            var $valid = $("#commentForm").valid();
            if(!$valid) {
                $validator.focusInvalid();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }); 
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
}); 
</script>
```

My input elements look like this here:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input class="required" id="question21" name="question2" required="" type="radio"> 1</label> 
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="question22" name="question2" type="radio"> 2</label> 
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="question23" name="question2" type="radio"> 3</label> 
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="question24" name="question2" type="radio"> 4</label> 
<label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input id="question25" name="question2" type="radio"> 5</label></div>
```

**Here the entire code of the site:**
http://chopapp.com/#aj3u0kz1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared the `required` rule twice in your HTML markup...

```
<input class="required" id="question21" name="question2" required="" type="radio">
```

1)  **By class:**  `class="required"` is declaring the `name="question2"` radio button set as **required**.

2)  **By HTML5 attribute:**  `required=""` is declaring the `name="question2"` radio button set as **not required**.

Apparently the jQuery Validation plugin gives precedence to the HTML5 attribute.

You only need to use one method of declaring the rule.  Use `class` or HTML5 attribute, not both.  If you decide to keep the HTML5 attribute, then use `required="required"`.

---

**EDIT**:

**Quote OP's Comment:**

> "... But *either* `class="required"` or `required="required"` works :-( Do you have another idea?"

Did you mean to say *"neither"* of those works?  Both of those work perfectly fine, as well as another method...

**Rule declared by `class="required"`:  http://jsfiddle.net/MHWmx/**

**Rule declared by `required="required"`:  http://jsfiddle.net/MHWmx/1/**

**Rule declared within `.validate()`:  http://jsfiddle.net/MHWmx/2/**

Otherwise, there's a problem in code you have not shown.

Comment: Thanks for the respond! But either class="required" or required="required" works :-( Do you have another idea?

Comment: Sorry, I mean neither. My fault! Your solutions are working both. But it works only, if I use Bootstrap 2. If I use Bootstrap 3, it doesn't work :-(